# JOIN Pulling 2 times rows than expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've 3 tables - Table tblFactorDefinition, tblFamily and tblConstituent.

- tblFactorDefinition has FamilyID with corrosponding Factors in FieldName Column(Namely Factor1, Factor2,.....Factor9)
- Table tblConstituent has associated Factors value (Value for Factor1, Factor2,..Factor9 if it exist) for each constituent within the Family and can be joined by FamilyID with FamilyID in tbLFacctorDefinition.
- Table tblFamily has Family details. (i.e. FamilyTypeID=1 is Index or and FamilyTypeID=2 is an ETF).

While trying to retrieve FamilyID with Factors corrosponding Factors Value in tblConstituent I get 2-3 times the rows. For example, FamilyID =10216 has 27975 constituents but my query fetches more than 55k+ rows. I am upto the wall trying to figure out JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tc.FamilyID, 
                tfd.FieldName, 
                tc.Factor1, 
                tc.Factor2, 
                tc.Factor3, 
                tc.Factor4, 
                tc.Factor5, 
                tc.Factor6, 
                tc.Factor7, 
                tc.Factor8, 
                tc.Factor9, 
                tf.OpenDate 
FROM   soladbserver..tblFamily tf 
       JOIN soladbserver..tblFactorDefinition tfd 
         ON tfd.FamilyID = tf.FamilyID 
       JOIN soladbserver..tblConstituent tc 
         ON tc.FamilyID = tf.FamilyID 
            AND tc.StartDate <= Getdate() 
            AND tc.EndDate > Getdate() 
WHERE  tf.OpenDate = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE) 
       AND tf.FamilyTypeID = 1 
       AND tf.DataProviderID = 2 
       AND tf.FamilyID IN ( 10216 )
```

I am expecting 27975 rows with factor values for corrosponding FieldName Factor1, Factor2,...,Factor9) given all has values.

[image: tblConstituent]

[image: tblFactorDefinition]

[image: tblFamily]
[image: tblFamily]
[image: tblFamiliy]

Screenshot 1 is tblConstituent table,
Secreenshot 2 is tblFactorDefinition table,
Screenshot 3,4,5 is tblFamily table:

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: As Juan Carlos said. You also need to provide some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: Can you try a left join?

Comment: Also you post 3 tables but dont put the table names so we dont know which one is each table. Also your query show field `Factor##` and `OpenDate` but not table have those fields

Comment: I've about 55k rows and actual output I expect is half of that. How can i upload data files?

Comment: You upload a sample data   Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Added rextester.com with dbschema. will insert sample data there. - https://rextester.com/XMYO76775

Comment: Full dataset with db schema uploaded to https://rextester.com/XMYO76775

Comment: Did you solve this? Do you still need to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the join to "Left Outer Join", and use the sql subquery select statement to pull the fieldname and see what you get. If the FamilyID a primary key in the tc table and a foreign key in the others, this should get you where you want to be.

```
SELECT tf.FamilyID, 
            (Select top 1 isNull(tfd.FieldName,'') from soladbserver..tblFactorDefinition tfd 
     where tfd.FamilyID = tf.FamilyID ) as FieldName, -- this assumes each familyID only has one tfd.FieldName -- if not change both to left outer joins and leave the rest as is and run it
            tc.Factor1, 
            tc.Factor2, 
            tc.Factor3, 
            tc.Factor4, 
            tc.Factor5, 
            tc.Factor6, 
            tc.Factor7, 
            tc.Factor8, 
            tc.Factor9, 
            tf.OpenDate 
FROM   soladbserver..tblFamily tf 
  left outer JOIN soladbserver..tblConstituent tc 
     ON tc.FamilyID = tf.FamilyID 
        AND tc.StartDate <= Getdate() 
        AND tc.EndDate > Getdate() 
WHERE  tf.OpenDate = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE) 
   AND tf.FamilyTypeID = 1 
   AND tf.DataProviderID = 2 
   AND tf.FamilyID IN ( 10216 )
```

Comment: This is pulling correct number of rows but your assumption that each Family has Only 1 FieldName is not true. Family can have upto Nine FiledName from Factor1, Factor2,...,Factor9.